# Manage route in security.yml with access_control

Tags: php, symfony, access-control

I want :

> **/p/{name}**    ==> in public access
>   **/profile**     ==> in loggin access

I did this in **security.yml**

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/[p]/* , role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_CONNECT }
```

But, when I browse :

**/profile** => accessible in public ==> **K.O.**
**/p/name-here** => accessible in public ==> **OK**

Comment: Please format your question. "**K.O.**" is not an error message for us. Add your routing, your complete `security.yml`, and the error message you get when you go to `/profile`. If you could also add a tag that match your symfony version, that would be perfect.

Comment: /profile is accessible in public so it KO (not good) because I want this route only when user is logged

Comment: It seemed to be pretty clear to me, and I think composer uses OK for success and KO as an error (KO is not OK). Besides, the problem is clearly stated immediately before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `^/[p]/*` is going to match any path that starts with `/p`, and you have it as the first rule, so it matches first and allows access.

The square brackets `[]` are defining a set of characters to match, you only want to match one so you don't need them. The `*` says to match zero or more `/` characters at the end, you know there will be one `/` after `p` so omit the star. The path is a prefix so you don't need to worry about the variable part of the path.

Try this:

```
- { path: ^/p/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/profile, role: ROLE_CONNECT }
```